# How to make FallbackResource look for file always on root

Tags: php, apache, front-controller

I'd like to create a Front Controller to process all requests to my PHP site.
So I created a routes.php in my site root: http://localhost:81/site/

My site is hosted on apache in my local machine, and /site is a alias configured in apache `httpd.conf`.

And configured .htaccess with the FallbackResource directive:

```
FallbackResource /routes.php
```

But then I get a 404 error to any URL I access.

So I changed to: (I'm on Windows)

```
FallbackResource \routes.php
```

It works when I access `http://localhost:81/site/mycontroller`, it calls routes.php, but when I tried to call `http://localhost:81/site/mycontroller/myaction`, I get an error. Exploring the log files, I discovered that apache is searching for routes.php in a /mycontroller directory (Which does not exists)

How do I Configure FallbackResource in a way that routes.php in site root will be called regardless of the structure of the URL used?

Comment: Have you tried `FallbackResource "route.php"` with or without `RewriteBase "/site/"`?

Comment: Documentation says, _"In a sub-URI, such as `http://example.com/blog/` this sub-URI has to be supplied as local-url:"_, and then gives `FallbackResource /blog/index.php` as the example in this case. So I think you would need `/site/routes.php` here then?

Comment: @CBroe, you are correct. That solved my problem, post this as a answer so I can mark as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html#fallbackresource) says,

> In a sub-URI, such as `http://example.com/blog/` this sub-URI has to be supplied as local-url: [...]

and then gives `FallbackResource /blog/index.php` as the example in this case.

So for your situation, you would need `/site/routes.php` here then.